# Uso de "->" y "::" en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy aprendiendo PHP y en una de las actividades requiero leer el codigo de alguien mas. Y hay lineas con esto:

```
->where()
   
->first() 

Calculation::where('id', ">=", 1)->update
```

No se a que se refieren las flechas **->** y los dos dobles puntos **::**

Tengo entendido que se suelen usar las flechas en **"this"** para hacer referencia al contexto actual del objeto, pero aun no entiendo con where y first, o sea, individualmente que es **"->"?** o siempre se acompaña de where? y a que hace referencia con first? Porque tengo entendido que **"Where"**, no es lo mismo que ->Where, o si? Segun vi que **"::"** se usa para la herencia. A lo mejor es algo muy facil pero prefiero preguntar porque no sale en la documentacion de PHP o quiza no se buscar

Comment: [*Operador de objeto*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.properties.php) y [*Operador de resolución de ámbito*](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

Answer (score 2):

Si estás aprendiendo PHP, ve paso a paso.

Lo digo porque te voy a decir la diferencia entre `->` y `::`, y posiblemente te quedes igual (o casi).

Ambos se usan para acceder a propiedades y métodos de una clase. La diferencia es que `->` se usa para acceder a propiedades y métodos **no estáticos**, mientras que `::` se usa para acceder a propiedades y métodos **estáticos**.

Además, `::` se usa también para acceder a las constantes de una clase (si tiene).

Te voy a poner un ejemplo:

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    static public $propiedadEstatica = 'Propiedad estática';
    public $propiedadNoEstatica = 'Propiedad no estática';

    const UNA_CONSTANTE = 'Una constante';

    static public function metodoEstatico()
    {
        return 'Método estático';
    }

    public function metodoNoEstatico()
    {
        return 'Método no estático';
    }
}

echo MyClass::$propiedadEstatica . '<br />';
echo MyClass::metodoEstatico() . '<br />';

$myClass = new MyClass();
echo $myClass->$propiedadNoEstatica . '<br />';
echo $myClass->metodoNoEstatico() . '<br />';

echo MyClass::UNA_CONSTANTE . '<br />';
```

Ahora supongo que sentirás curiosidad por saber bien qué es eso de "estático" (`static`). También puede que te preguntes por qué uso `MyClass` con `::` pero uso `$myClass` con `->`. Por supuesto, está relacionado con `static`.

Está bien, la curiosidad no es mala, te animo a seguir investigando por ti mismo. Pero además no olvides seguir el método de aprendizaje.

Answer (score 2):

Te explico:

**Primero**

```
->where()
->first()
```

esto es un metodo propietario del desarrollador o Framework; quiere decir que estan en algun lugar del codigo fuente escrito por los desarrolladores de la plataforma o framework; no conosco ninguna extension de php que tenga estos metodos.

***Segundo:***

```
Calculation::where('id', ">=", 1)->update
```

los dos puntos dobles seguidos  `::` se les conoce como el [Operador de Resolucion de Ambito (Paamayim Nekudotayim)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) y no es mas que la sintaxis para acceder a elementos estatis y constantes de una clase.

Luego tienes `->` lo cual le llamamo el [Operador de Objetos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php) y no es mas que la sintaxis para acceder a elementos de un objetos, excepto las constantes y estaticos:

Ahora te dejare un ejemplo basado en el metodo que has presentado como luciria la clase:

```
<?php

class Calculation
{
    
    const default = ['id' => 5];
    
    private static ?Calculation $instance = null;
    
    public static $update = null;
    
    public static function where($label,$operator,$value): Calculation
    {
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }
        
        $evaluation = (
            isset(self::default[$label]) && 
            eval("return ".self::default[$label]." $operator $value;")
        );
        
        self::$update=$evaluation;
       
        return self::$instance;
    }
    
    public function update(){
        return self::$update;
    }
}


var_dump(Calculation::where('id', ">=", 1)->update());
```

***ouput:***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]